# How can I catch file > print event in Firefox add-on?

Tags: events, printing, firefox-addon

I want to create a Firefox add-on with which I catch the "file > print" browser event for stop it. Does anyone know how to catch this event? I find in browser.xul file the command:

```
   <command id="cmd_print" oncommand="goDoCommand('cmd_print')"/>
```

Can I catch goDoCommand('cmd_print') event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier thing to do would be to simply overlay the command so it does nothing.

In your XUL overlay, do this:

```
<commandset id="mainCommandSet">
  <command id="cmd_print" oncommand=""/>
</commandset>
```

This should cause nothing to happen when cmd_print is executed.